# Jest Test: Worker is not defined and Worker is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am currently developing a crm app and it has ant design charts in it. I'm trying to test one of the Pie's from antdesign charts, but when i run "npm run test" an error occures:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function

     >  7 | import { Pie } from '@ant-design/plots'
```

I'm fixing this error by adding a code line into testSetupFile.js which is :

```
Object.defineProperty(URL, 'createObjectURL', {
 writable: true,
 value: jest.fn(),
 })
```

After This one, i'm starting to get a new error :

```
● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

Lastly, I'm fixing this error, by creating a random worker and error turns into "Worker is not a constructor"

file.test.js:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
     >  7 | import PageThatContainsPie from './PageThatContainsPie'


describe('Pie Test', () => {
  test('it should mount', () => {
    const { container } = render(<PageThatContainsPie />)
  })
})
```

I just want to test it whether its getting rendered or not...

I've tried adding packagejson jsdom-worker aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my `setupTests.ts` file fixed it for me:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL = function () {
  return "";
};
if (typeof Worker === "undefined") {
  global.Worker = class {
    addEventListener() {}

    removeEventListener() {}

    dispatchEvent() {
      return false;
    }

    onmessage() {}

    onmessageerror() {}

    onerror() {}

    postMessage() {}

    terminate() {}
  };
}
```